# what happens at the text segment in memory layout when executing file?

Tags: c, memory

when excuting file, what happens at the text segment in memory layout?
do the code which is excuted now, appear at the text segment?

```
int A;
int myarray[40] = {1,2,3,4};
int f1(int i)
{
    int j = 5;
    int *p;

    j += i;
    p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    return j;
}

void main(){
    int k;
    k = 5;

    A = f1(k+5);
}
```

Comment: Being a purely technical question, this belongs to StackOverflow (please don't repost it there though, it will be automigrated if enough people vote to close it here).

Comment: Not sure I get your point.  Wouldn't A be assigned to 5 in your example?  Is this supposed to manipulate your array in some manner?

Comment: "int my array" is not valid C, this won't compile so it's hard to say how it will behave once it's running. :)

Comment: not only does this question not make sense but the code does not compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text segment contains all the program's compiled machine code, not just the code that's currently running at any given moment.  Unless you're doing unusual advanced things like overlays or self-modifying code, the text segment is read-only and never changes while the program runs.

Comment: thanks:) however, is only binary code appear at the text segment? if f1 function is excuted, only the binary instruction code of f1 appear?

Comment: @KayKay: that's up to the compiler. It's normal to have string literals and constant pools in the code segment too, not sure whether you would consider that "binary code" or not.

Comment: @KayKay, yes, only executable code goes in the text segment.  Initialized data, like the contents of your global array, goes in the data segment.  Uninitialized data, like your `int A`, goes in the BSS segment.